# Why if we have a singular covariance matrix then the data is over fitted?

Tags: covariance-matrix, overfitting

If we have *D* dimensional training data and the covariance matrix was not exist for those data, then we have over fitting. I think this is related to make sure that the observations must has low correlation, but I cannot understand how can we observe data from the same source and we expect that they have low correlation. What am I missing here?